# How to set the arr.reverse() value to the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down and I need to remove options after 2003  i achieved it but the thing is I need to show by order 2015 to 2003. I tried to reverse the array but I am unable achieve it. I have provided the jsfiddle link for reference.

**JS Code:**

```
var date = new Date();
var curYr = date.getFullYear();
curYr = curYr + 1;
var yrs = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    yrs.push((curYr - i).toString());
}
$('select option').filter(function () {
    return $.inArray(this.innerHTML, yrs) == -1
}).remove();
```

**Fiddler:Link**

**[Code Sample Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ttv78z26/2/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work :

After this js code :

```
$('select option').filter(function () {
   return $.inArray(this.innerHTML, yrs) == -1
}).remove();
```

write this :

```
$('select option').each(function () {
   $('select').prepend($(this))  //or in place of '$(this)' you can only use 'this'.
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x0tm3yjd/)

**NOTE :-** To be more specific you can use `id` or `class` selector if there are more then one select tags in your html.